# Is there a way to handle the event when a new thread is created in the current process?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to able to detect when a new thread is created e.g. `Task.Run` and, if possible, handle when its closed.

I know it's possible to get the current threads being handled by your process via `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` and that's somewhat useful. What I want though it's to handle when a new thread begin it's execution, from a perspective that I don't know where it's been created.

**Some background**

As it was asked, I'm putting here some detail to the actual problem I'm running into, because maybe I'm searching for the least optimal solution.

I'm developing a large system with multiple screen, each one with a bunch of controls, which some of them are custom. Recently, the team has gradually been adopting async/await patterns and the issue of locking the UI untill a task is completed has risen. We created a loading panel in our base form, exposing a hide and show method to be called by the implementations of this base form. The problem here is returning to all those forms that are already implemented and placing calls to those methods throughout the code, especially async events. Here I wonder if there's an easier solution that will work for the past implementations and eliminate the need of calling methods between events.

What we are doing as in today, is something along the lines:

```
public class BaseForm {
    public ShowPanel(){
        ...
    }

    public HidePanel(){
        ...
    }
}

public class FormImplementation : BaseForm {
    private async void OnEventAsync(object sender, EventArgs e){
        ShowPanel();
        // await stuff
        HidePanel();
    }
}
```

I find it to be quite cumbersome to manually place those calls around event handlers. I'd do some metaprogramming karate, but I'm not experienced with it in C#.

Comment: `Task.Run` is not the same thing as "a new thread is created" - tasks and threads are *completely different concepts*; there is no event for thread creation; if you want to know everything about folks using `Task.Run`, you could perhaps write your own `TaskScheduler` (but note: `Task.Run` always uses the default scheduler - you'd need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` passing in your custom scheduler to see that), but : this isn't for the faint-hearted. To echo what @mjwills says above: *what are you actually trying to achieve here*, because ... at the moment it sounds very confused

Comment: you need to ensure that the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is used appropriately

Comment: @MarcGravell,I provided some background to the problem. You see, I don't think it's a simple one, because the easier solution (placing calls throughout the code) don't cover the demand well enough and put one more burden on the developer during implementation.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. What does "the issue of locking the UI untill a task is completed has risen" mean? Perhaps you can reduce the actual problem down to a single instance, preferably with a code sample.

Comment: @StephenCleary, there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe I'm searching for the least optimal solution.

Examining threads is definitely an incorrect approach. For one, [`async` doesn't use threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), so that approach would not have worked.

> I find it to be quite cumbersome to manually place those calls around event handlers. I'd do some metaprogramming karate, but I'm not experienced with it in C#.

Metaprogramming is one option, and a pretty decent one. PostSharp and Fody are both highly regarded. The "do something at the beginning and end of these methods" is a common problem in that field, and metaprogramming is a definite option. I think what you actually want is something like this:

```
public class BaseForm {
    public ShowPanel() {
        ...
    }

    public HidePanel() {
        ...
    }
}

public class FormImplementation : BaseForm {
    private async void OnEventAsync(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ShowPanel();
        try { ... }
        finally { HidePanel(); }
    }
}
```

You can minimize the code changes by using a disposable, e.g., (using [my Nito.Disposables library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Disposables)) with a C# 8 [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration):

```
public class BaseForm {
    public IDisposable ShowPanel() {
        ...
        return new AnonymousDisposable(HidePanel);
    }

    private void HidePanel() {
        ...
    }
}

public class FormImplementation : BaseForm {
    private async void OnEventAsync(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using var _ = ShowPanel();
        ...
    }
}
```

There are other alternatives, such as changing the return type of `OnEventAsync` to be `Task`, but that would require more code changes I think than just doing the above.